# What's the cleanest way to get the current local time in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a more succinct way to write the following in Postgres:

```
DATE(NOW() AT TIME ZONE time_zone)
```

i.e. to get the local time for a record with time zone `time_zone`?

Ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
NOW(time_zone)
```

That doesn't work but is there anything similar and clean I can use?

Comment: You can easily write such a function

Comment: Thanks for that - you answered exactly what I asked. I was actually wanting to use it in the context of Rails (which I didn't mention) so have also added a link to a question which shows how to add in calculated attributes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=> SELECT DATE(NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC');
2013-11-19

=> SELECT DATE(NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'PST');
2013-11-18
```

**UPDATE**:

If you're looking to abstract this query into a [custom function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/xfunc-sql.html), you can create one as follows:

```
=> CREATE FUNCTION date_with_time_zone() RETURNS date AS '
     SELECT DATE(NOW() AT TIME ZONE ''PST'');
     ' LANGUAGE SQL;
CREATE FUNCTION

=> SELECT date_with_time_zone();
2013-11-18
```

While you still need to issue the `SELECT` command, the current date with time zone will be returned simply by invoking the function, rather than the entire query.

Comment: Thanks for offering this. It's the same as the original one I posted though no? I'm trying to make it less verbose as it's making the SQL in a larger query (even more) complex to read.